# Toolbar Button and SendMessage() Function Difficulties

Tags: winapi

I want to make a program (program 1) that will click a toolbar button on another program (program 2). I have the handle of the window the toolbar button is in and I have its button ID. At first I thought I could use the function:

```
SendMessage (buttonHandle, BN_CLICK, 0, 0);
```

but I have no clue as to how to get the handle of the tool bar button. I tried to use the function:

```
GetDlgItem ( windowHandle, buttonID);
```

but it doesn't work. I also have been told that since it's a toolbar button, there is no specific handle for it... kind of odd, not sure how that works...

Question 1:: is there a handle for toolbar buttons and how may I get it?

Question 2 (MAIN AND MOST IMPORTANT QUESTION!):: what function can I use to click on a toolbar button? (please mention the parameters for the function too)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a handle for toolbar buttons and how may I get it?

No. Toolbar buttons are non-windowed. They do not have window handles.

> What function can I use to click on a toolbar button?

You use [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684076.aspx) to automate other applications.

Comment: I have heard of UI Automation and didn't want to get into it. Do you know any function that can click on the toolbar button? I am not asking for a library.

Comment: You are expected to use UI Automation. I don't understand why you wish to avoid the right solution for your problem. This is a solution that was built with the express purpose of solving your problem. It is perfect for that.

Comment: Well for 1 I have already done some good code on locating the specific window handle amongst other properties such as toolbar button ID, etc, and jumping into another library might make that unnecessary. Between trying to find 1 appropriate function or going into a totally new library and possibly modifying all my other code, Id prefer to take a shoot and trying to find a single function first that would complete all that I have done already. If that fails I can always go and spend a few hours learning UI Automation.

Comment: The answer is always UI Automation. You'd be done by now if you'd started when we first told you about it.

Comment: ahhh.. saying that you don't know what function I could use would of been enough. I'll definitely look up UI Automation later on if I fail to find what I am looking for, thnx for your feedback.

Comment: There are certainly hacky ways to fake clicks on toolbar buttons. I could certainly work it out. But there's no point.

Comment: I'm sure there are, but I mean, if there are msgs in SendMessage that press down the toolbar button I want (which I have found to be TB_PRESSBUTTON)... I mean there has to be something that isn't that hacky. It shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: It is hacky. UI Automation is not. What you are asking for is the `NM_CLICK` notification. Not much fun faking that. Try not to get too much sand in your ears.

Comment: I guess you didnt read my last comment, I said there hassss to be sometthing that isn't that hacky!! When you say "it is hacky", your talking about that other funky stuff, I'm saying there should be some function that does what I want given its so simple and since there are so mannny other functions that do similar things, both on buttons and on toolbar buttons. My ears are fine, check your eyes though.

Comment: Yes I read it. What you are attempting to do is a blatant hack. You just don't see it that way. But a hack it is. Sending notification messages is a hack. The sand gets in your ears when you bury your head in it. I do find it rather amazing how many questions are asked here by people who cannot accept that UI Automation is the way to do automation.

Comment: Its not a hack. Having a program do your clicking for you cause your lazy is just as hacky as my mouse doing my clicking since the mouse and computer communicate there clicks through notification messages. My heads not in the sand, but I guess that is hard to see when your eyes aren't in tip top shape, don't worry, apology accepted.

Comment: It really is a hack. You just don't see it yet.

Comment: Nice come back bra. UI Automation uses the same notification messages. The point of a conversation is to exchange ideas and obtain the best results. Saying "you just don't see it" is neither helpful nor good practice for future conversations you will probably have.

Comment: We disagree. You aren't going to agree with me. I'm not going to agree with you. What else are we going to do. Not much for for either of us to say.

Comment: You don't agree with me that it is worth the time to search for a possibly simple solution (being that solution a function that will mimic what SendMessage(buttonHandle, BN_CLICK, 0, 0) does but for toolbar buttons) and finish a fair amount of code already developed rather than go into UI Automation right away and possibly scrap all that has been done so far? I believe a small amount of time and effort is the efficient thing to do. No one is questioning if UI Automation is good, the question lies in what is the most effective course of action.

Comment: @user3552287 Ultimately that's your problem and not really useful for future visitors. You can try faking an `NM_CLICK` notification.

Comment: You said we disagree, I am just saying what we disagree in which is the approach that is most effective. A discussion can't be a problem to anyone so you saying "Ultimately that's your problem" isn't an appropriate reference to my asking if you agree with me if I should search a bit more before going into UI Automation. Stay on topic brooo

Comment: I am an topic. A discussion is not a problem, but we've finished discussing. I am of one opinion, you another. Which is fine. Ultimately, your own personal choices with your problem are a matter for you alone. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site. I've tried to answer the questions that you ask. You get to judge whether or not that is the case.

Comment: Actually, I'm not even certain that `NM_CLICK` faking gets you anywhere.